# join columns on the same table without declaring a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complex query to populate data and after than
i have to join the data in the table to get the right result.

How to eliminate the join such that i do not have to define the table two times.

The join query being -

```
 select t1.acc_no, t1.group_id, t1.remdt from @tbl t1
 inner join ( 
     select group_id, MAX(row_num) as max_row from @tbl group by group_id) t2 
   on t1.group_id= t2.group_id and t1.row_num=t2.max_row
```

now in the above query i have to decalre @tbl temp table.

How to get the same result such that i dont have to do using the join and do not have to write the same query twice.

My @tbl is populated using the sql -

```
  select  ReminderDt as 'rem dt',  m.Group_Id, m.AccountNumber,
row_number() over (partition by group_id order by reminderdt asc) as seqnum
from ACE_AccsLevelTran t join ACE_AccsLevelMaster m on t.MasterAccNumber=m.AccountNumber where m.AssignedUser=7
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a window function, `row_number()`:

```
select  t.acc_no, t.group_id, t.remdt
from (select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by group_id order by row_num desc) as seqnum
      from @tbl t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: where seqnum=1 will give the least date, i want the max date

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya . . . The `order by` has a `desc` modifier, so the largest value will have the value "1".